# ExerciseList after answer more distance

Tags: exercises

How can I set more distance between Question and Answer? Also, indent the answer more?

```
\begin{ExerciseList}
\Exercise{Blabla}
  \Question{Hier steht die Frage}
  \Answer{Hier steht die Antwort 
  }
\end{ExerciseList}
```

My attempt:

```
\let\OldAnswer\Answer
\renewcommand{\OldAnswer}{\vspace{1cm}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\setlength{\Exesep}{2\baselineskip}
\setlength{\Exetopsep}{2\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\AnswerListHeader}{\hspace{1cm}\textbf{\AnswerListName\
(\ExerciseListName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB)\ ---\ }}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
Some text.
\section{My section}
Some other text.
\begin{ExerciseList}
\Exercise{Blabla}
  \Question{Hier steht die Frage}
  \Answer{Hier steht die Antwort}
\end{ExerciseList}
And some text at the end.
\end{document}
```

[image]